# One @click event with multiple toggles

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, toggle

I have one  element. I would like to add 3 different toggles with one @click:

1. toggle hidden nested `<p>`
2. toggle `<i>` element
3. toggle background color of parent box `(.faq-box)`

What is the best way to do this in vue.js?

I have deleted some data objects etc, just left behind what is applicable on the desired element.

This is the HTML element:

```
<div v-for="item in faqItems" v-bind:class="[isActive ? 'faq-box-white' : 'faq-box-warmgrey']" class="box faq-box is-shadowless has-py-3" @click="toggleFaq($event)">
        <div class="columns is-mobile">
            <div class="column">
                <li class="">
                 <span class="is-size-7-mobile has-text-weight-semibold collapse">
                                            {{ item.question }}
                </span>
                <p class="is-size-7 has-text-weight-normal is-hidden has-pt-4" v-html="item.answer">
                </p>
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-1 has-p-1">
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down is-pulled-right has-pt-3"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

new Vue({
    el: '#appName',
    data: {
        isActive: true,
        },
    methods: {
        toggleFaq: function(event) {

            let el = event.target.parentNode.children[1];
            console.log(el);

            // console.log(document.querySelector("i").classList);
            let el_icon = document.querySelector("i").classList;
            console.log(el_icon);
                // el_icon.classList.toggle("fa-caret-up");
                // el_icon.classList.toggle("fa-caret-down");

            if(el.classList.contains('is-hidden')){
                el.classList.remove('is-hidden')
            } else {
                el.classList.add('is-hidden')
            }

            el = event.target.parentNode.children[0];
            if(el.classList.contains('collapse')){
                el.classList.remove('collapse')
            } else {
                el.classList.add('collapse')
            }

            //toggle background color
            if(this.isActive){
                this.isActive = false;
            }else{
                this.isActive = true;
            }

        },
```

Comment: make the same kind of conditional `:class` for `is-hidden` and `is-pulled-right` as you do for `faq-box-white`. They will all use `isActive` as their test.

Comment: @RoyJ  Thank you, I'm almost there, but still need some help with one more thing. The toggles are now all active with the conditional classes added as you suggested. However the `<div v-for="item in faqItems">` is linked to data with 16 questions so it renders this element 16 times. Now when I click on one question all of the questions get toggled, not just the one that is being clicked on. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will need another variable to store which is the active `faqItem`, and base your conditions on that.

Comment: @RoyJ Thank you for you help, together with DigitalDrifter 's solution below it is now working perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @RoyJ, you need an active state for each FAQ. You can achieve this by adding a boolean flag to the FAQ box items.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          question: 'Question 1',
          answer: 'Answer 1',
          active: false
        },
        {
          question: 'Question 2',
          answer: 'Answer 2',
          active: false
        },
        {
          question: 'Question 3',
          answer: 'Answer 3',
          active: false
        },
        {
          question: 'Question 4',
          answer: 'Answer 4',
          active: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.faq-box {
  background-color: rgba(128, 222, 234, 1);
  width: 200px;
}

.faq-box.active {
  background-color: rgba(197, 225, 165, 1);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <li v-for="item in items" :class="{ faqBox: true, active: item.active }" class="box faq-box is-shadowless has-py-3" @click="item.active = !item.active">
    <div>
      <span>{{ item.question }}</span>
      <p v-show="item.active" v-html="item.answer"></p>
    </div>
    <i :class="{ fa: true, 'fa-caret-down': item.active, 'fa-caret-up': !item.active }"></i>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, the combination of answers has it working perfectly now!